# Stringifying a object and then parsing it back to its original object?

Tags: javascript, object

```
Order
   props: Object
   selectedItems: Array[1]
    0: SelectedItem
    length: 1
   __proto__: Array[0]
__proto__: Order
```

I have an Array of Objects "SelectedItem".

What I need to do is Stringify the Array of objects in selectedItems to store in localstorage.

Then I would like to parse them back into objects. It seems if I use parseJSON() I get a standard object returned instead of a SelectedItem Object. Is there a proper way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Only object literals can be expressed in JSON, so the object you get back won't have its previous `[[Prototype]]`. It shouldn't be too much trouble to make a new `SelectedItem` instance from the returned plain object though.

Comment: I ended up having to stringify the object then create the objects manually and use the data from the standard object rebuilt from $.parseJSON().